# Prove that $\lim_{t\to \infty} u(x,t) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Suppose 
>   $$
> u(x,t)= \frac 1{\sqrt{4\pi kt}} \int_\Bbb R e^\frac {-(x-y)^2}{4kt}g(y)dy
> $$
>   where $g \in L^1(\Bbb R)$. Here the set of functions $L^1(\Bbb R)$ defined as 
>   $$
> L^1(\Bbb R) := \{\varphi:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R\ : \int_\Bbb R |\varphi (x)|dx < \infty\}
> $$
>   Prove that $$\lim_{t\to \infty} u(x,t) = 0$$

---

Now what I think I have to do is show that $|u(x,t)|$ has an upper bound and I can say that it is bounded by a function at all points. Then show this function converges $\to 0$ as $t \to \infty$

Comment: I am unable to see   how could be true that $g \in L^1$, $g$ is constant

Comment: My thinking is that because $g \in L^1(\Re)$ then you dont have to worry about the $g(y)$ part in $u(x,t)$ as it is bounded?

Comment: sorry I edited my comment changing its meaning: but I still do not get your point, how can $g$ be constant and be $L^1$?

Comment: $u(x,t)$ is $g(y)=u_0$, a constant over the real line, multiplied by a Gaussian measure with mean $x$ and variance $2kt$. Does that mean a Gaussian measure is no longer a probability measure as its variance tends to infinity? Note that the answers below assume $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but as An aedonist mentioned, that can't be true, right?

Comment: @Autonomous49: The line *"I am also told to assume that $g(x)=u_0$ is a constant function for all $u_0 \in \mathbb R$"* makes absolutely no sense, as remarked by others commenters as well.

Comment: @AlexM.  Hi, sorry about my late reply, but yes the question does state in part ii) that I am to assume $g(x)=u_0$ is a constant function, $u_0 \in \Re$. Unless for part iii), the part I have a problem with, I should disregard this part about g(x) being a constant function.

Comment: @Anaedonist I now think that the question is really poorly worded, and that I shouldnt assume that g(x) is constant as I am assuming that form an earlier part of the question. So I'll edit my question

Comment: Since, $$0\le e^\frac {-(x-y)^2}{4kt} \le 1$$
we have, 
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}|u(x,t)|\le \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac 1{\sqrt{4\pi kt}} \int_\Bbb R e^\frac {-(x-y)^2}{4kt}|g(y)|dy \\=\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac 1{\sqrt{4\pi kt}} \int_\Bbb R|g(y)|dy =  \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac {\|g\|_1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}} =0 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
  |u(x,t)| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi k t}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|g(x)|dx \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } t\rightarrow\infty.
$$